# Decrease table row height of mud (material-ui) below the minimum height?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to decrease the height of a react mui table row with the following methods:

Firstly, in `index.css`:

```css
tr{
    height:20px;
}
```

Secondly, in source code `app.js`:

```js
...
<TableRow style={{height: 5}}>
    <TableCell>
        hello
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell>
        hello
    </TableCell>
</TableRow>
...
```

And the `makeStyle` and `useStyle` methods of `@mui/styles`.

All the methods can succeed, but the problem is that, if I decrease the height below a certain value, then it stops working. All I have in the table are texts, and **the program refuses to decrease table row height even when we can still see a wide margin between the text and the table row separation line.**

**Is there a way to force mui to decrease the row height below this value?** Do we have the option to decrease the height all the way to zero (even though that will make text invisible)?